colorScheme for both iPhone and iPad - SwiftUI
I can't get my view - MyAccountView - to display correctly in both iPad and iPhone. I have to change code every time. The problem is this piece:
ZStack {
        
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        // Dynamic Animated Gradient
    }

When I have the ZStack right below the var body the it displays everything correctly for iOS, but when I try to open it on iPad OS I get a completely blank screen except for a small button in the top left corner. When I remove the ZStack then it works correctly on iPad OS but in IOS I get a completely blank screen.
Full code:
struct MyAccountView: View {
    @StateObject private var userProfileViewModel = UserProfileViewModel()
    @State private var showSettingsSheet = false
    @State private var showHighlightsSheet = false
    @State private var showNotesSheet = false
    @State private var showBookmarkedPostsSheet = false
    @State private var highlightsSheet: HighlightsView?
    @State private var notesSheet: NotesView?
    @State private var bookmarkedPostsSheet: BookmarkedPostsView?
    @State var rotation: Double = 0
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme  // Access the current color scheme
    


    var body: some View {
        
        
        

        ZStack {
            
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            // Dynamic Animated Gradient
        }
        Circle()
                .fill(LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: colorScheme == .dark ?
                                       [Color(red: 222/255, green: 78/255, blue: 98/255), Color(red: 161/255, green: 58/255, blue: 161/255)] :
                                        [Color(red: 245/255, green: 200/255, blue: 220/255), Color(red: 230/255, green: 210/255, blue: 240/255)]), // Stronger shades for light mode
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom
                ))
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .blur(radius: 40)
                .opacity(colorScheme == .dark ? 0.8 : 1)  // Changed opacity for light mode
                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(rotation))
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .onAppear() {
                    animateIndefinitely()
                }
            
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
            }
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                VStack {
                    UserProfileView(viewModel: userProfileViewModel)
                        .padding()
                    
                    ShimmeringProgressBar(xp: Double(userProfileViewModel.xp), level: userProfileViewModel.level)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))], spacing: 20) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: HighlightsView(highlights: userProfileViewModel.highlights)) {
                                AccountButton(title: "Highlights", icon: "star.fill")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: NotesListView(viewModel: userProfileViewModel)) {
                                AccountButton(title: "Notes", icon: "note.text")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: BookmarkedPostsView(bookmarkedPosts: $userProfileViewModel.bookmarkedPosts)) {
                                AccountButton(title: "Bookmarks", icon: "bookmark.fill")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: FriendsView(viewModel: userProfileViewModel)) {
                                AccountButton(title: "Friends", icon: "person.2.fill")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.top, 60)

                
                Button(action: {
                    showSettingsSheet = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsSheet) {
                    SettingsSheetView()
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private func updateHighlights() {
        if let highlightsView = highlightsSheet {
            userProfileViewModel.updateHighlights(highlightsView.editedHighlights)
        }
    }

    private func updateNotes() {
        if let notesView = notesSheet {
            userProfileViewModel.updateNotes(notesView.editedNotes)
        }
    }

    private func updateBookmarkedPosts() {
        if let bookmarkedPostsView = bookmarkedPostsSheet {
            userProfileViewModel.bookmarkedPosts = bookmarkedPostsView.editedPosts
        }
    }
    private func animateIndefinitely() {
        let rotationAnim = Animation.linear(duration: 10).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        let scaleAnim = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
        
        withAnimation(rotationAnim) {
            rotation += 360
        }
        
        withAnimation(scaleAnim) {
            scale = 1.2
        }
    }
}

I've tried adding code that will make the ZStack only on iOS but it still doesn't work, and I've also tried moving around other pieces and watching tutorials.
Here's a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue:
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Adrian Martinez on 5/26/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }

            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .padding()
            }

            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int {
    case unspecified
    
    case phone // iPhone and iPod touch style UI
    case pad   // iPad style UI (also includes macOS Catalyst)
}

extension View {
    var isIPad: Bool {
        UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]; ideally something that can be pasted into Xcode and run to demonstrate the problem.
